# Despite extending TimeSpan the user still logs out

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to keep user logged in for longer time, like a year or so. So I changed the

TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),

to

TimeSpan.FromDays(365),

in my startup.auth.cs

as seen in the code blow, however the user still logs out after a short time. What did I do wrong here?

```
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

and here is related setting in my web.config

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Is the user logged out from your web site? What is the timeout value in Web.config?

Comment: @SivaGopal it is not explicitly set at the web.config. ( I added the related settings at web.config) ( iam using the default MVC5 scaffolding project)